# How to output html content to command prompt using python

Tags: python-3.x

```
#bug: this program should output url contents but instead outputs the urls themselves
import csv
import requests
import json
with open('PluginIndex.csv', newline='') as csvfile: #opens the plugin index file and stores in var "csvfile"
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile) #reads the contents of csvfile and stores it
    for row in reader: #for each row of text in the contents of csv
        url = row["repo"]
        print(url) #outputs the repo url of each csv row
        resp = requests.get(url)
        data = json.loads(resp.text)
        data.keys()
```

I need the content of each url in a csv file to be outputted to the command prompt, however the requests and json libraries are not enough. Does anyone know a way to achieve this?

Comment: Is there some specific content you are interested in? `print(resp.text)` prints all of it. There is no need for json.

Comment: I am interested in printing the html elements without the tags, so only the plain text is outputted without any markup, styling or interactivity. E.g. a line of code <h1>Hello World!</h1> would be printed as "Hello World!" without any tags.

Comment: It's rather hard to give you any specific answers without knowing the contents of `PluginIndex.csv`, but here's one good place to start learning http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/